# How to upload csv files in lightning and create records from it

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to upload csv file into lightning component and get the data from that csv file and need to create the records into custom objects using that csv.I am new to lightning.How can we achieve this using lightning.Any links for reference?

Comment: this post should lead you in the right direction. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243799/how-to-parse-csv-file-in-lightning-javascript